# sum of absolute differences of two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to find how similar a picture is to some samples that I have (black and white). 
I use the sum of absolute difference code, but because I'm new to MATLAB I didn't find out how to use it. How does this algorithm work? Does it give a measure of how similar the pics are?

---

```
I= imread('img1.jpg');

image2= imread('img2.jpg');


% J = uint8(filter2(fspecial('gaussian'), I));

K = imabsdiff(I,image2);

figure, imshow(K,[])
```

Comment: If your question is how does sum of absolute differences work: 1. [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences) and 2. [`imabsdiff` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html).

Comment: `imabsdiff` does exactly what the documentation says. How you define your similarity metric, thus what you _do_ with the absolute difference, is entirely up to you - `sum(K(:))` is one option.

Comment: I presume that this function is mostly used for continuous frames of a video. This way you can tell that how much movements exist in two sequential frames. Otherwise this kind of difference could not be a good criterion.

Answer (score 5):

Well I think you pretty much answered your question yourself. It is the sum of the absolute difference. So let say you have `img1` and `img2` which are the same size and type.

To find the difference, do subtraction

```
img1-img2
```

To find the absolute difference, use the absolute value function `abs`

```
abs(img1-img2)
```

To find the sum, use the `sum` function. Note that you will need to do this for each "dimension" your image has. If you are not sure, type `size(img1)` and see if there are 2 or 3 numbers that show up, this corresponds to how many `sum(...)` you need to use.

For a color image (3 dimensions):

```
sum(sum(sum(abs(img1-img2))))
```

^^ Is the sum of the absolute differences. Whichever has the smallest sum can be considered the closest image.

If you have different sized images, you need to use the normxcorr2 function. This function will return a matrix of the same size with how well the template (small) image fits into the big image at each different point. Find the maximum value of that matrix and that is how well that image fits.

For instance:

```
correlation = normxcorr2(smallImg, bigImg);
compareMe = max(correlation(:))
```

Comment: I'd suggest `sum(abs(img1(:)-img2(:)))` as a simpler method, but still good answer.

Comment: i try to use this method but i had a problem i think is something with the size of the image... but i dont know                     ??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> sad at 4
sum(abs(image1(:)-image2(:)))

Comment: That is because your images aren't the same size. I added how to do this for different sized images, but be aware that it is much more computationally expensive. Good call on the img1(:) chappjc, much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to use `MATLAB`'s build-in function `imabsdiff`. In contrast to the other suggested answers, it takes care of the range boundaries if your image is formatted as `uint8`. Consider:

```
img1 = uint8(10);
img2 = uint8(20);
sum(abs(img1(:)-img2(:)))
```

gives you 0, whereas

```
imabsdiff(img1(:),img2(:))
```

correctly gives 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) in MATLAB you will be able to do so in Vectorized manner.
Just arrange each neighborhood in columns (For each frame).
Put them in 3D Matrix and apply you operation on the 3rd dimension.

#### Code Snippet

I used Wikipedia's definition of "[Sum of Absolute Differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_absolute_differences)".

The demo script:

```

```
% Sum of Absolute Differences Demo

numRows = 10;
numCols = 10;

refBlockRadius = 1;
refBlockLength = (2 * refBlockRadius) + 1;

mImgSrc     = randi([0, 255], [numRows, numCols]);
mRefBlock   = randi([0, 255], [refBlockLength, refBlockLength]);

mSumAbsDiff = SumAbsoluteDifferences(mImgSrc, mRefBlock);
```

```

The Function `SumAbsoluteDifferences`:

```

```
function [ mSumAbsDiff ] = SumAbsoluteDifferences( mInputImage, mRefBlock )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

blockLength = size(mRefBlock, 1);
blockRadius = (blockLength - 1) / 2;

mInputImagePadded = padarray(mInputImage, [blockRadius, blockRadius], 'replicate', 'both');

mBlockCol = im2col(mInputImagePadded, [blockLength, blockLength], 'sliding');

mSumAbsDiff = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, mBlockCol, mRefBlock(:))));

mSumAbsDiff = col2im(mSumAbsDiff, [blockLength, blockLength], [(numRows + blockLength - 1), (numCols + blockLength - 1)]);


end
```

```

Enjoy...